# Why does xparse refuse to label this edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xparse

The following code runs fine and does what I want when I delete the label instruction `["f"]` in the line `\draw[->] (A) edge["f"] (B);`.  And on the other hand the instructions with that label (and other edge labels) ran fine when they were not in an `xparse` command definition.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Triangle{ O{} r() m m m}{\begin{scope}[#1]\node at (#2) (A) {#3};
      \node at ($(#2)+(1,1.5)$) (B) {#4};
      \node at ($(#2)+(2,0)$) (C) {#5};
      \draw[->] (A) edge["f"] (B);
      \draw[->] (B) edge (C);
      \draw[->] (A) edge (C);
      \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Triangle[rotate=30](0,0) 0 1 2;
        \Triangle[rotate=-10](2.5,0) 0 1 2;
        \Triangle(5,0) 0 1 2;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

How can I get `xparse` to admit the label?  I am sure it is a simple answer but I have not found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `xparse`, in order to use the `".."` syntax for labels, you have to load the `quotes` library of TikZ, i.e. add `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`.

Your code does not work outside a macro definition either, if it did, I'm guessing it was in a document where the `quotes` library was loaded.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes} % <-- added quotes
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\Triangle{ O{} r() m m m}{\begin{scope}[#1]\node at (#2) (A) {#3};
      \node at ($(#2)+(1,1.5)$) (B) {#4};
      \node at ($(#2)+(2,0)$) (C) {#5};
      \draw[->] (A) edge["f"] (B);
      \draw[->] (B) edge (C);
      \draw[->] (A) edge (C);
      \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Triangle[rotate=30](0,0) 0 1 2;
        \Triangle[rotate=-10](2.5,0) 0 1 2;
        \Triangle(5,0) 0 1 2;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah.  In my main document I had loaded tikzlibrary `cd`.  That apparently includes `quotes`.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Yes, that is correct.